# Adding second swift file in Objective-c project has no effect

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an objective-c project working. Now added swift file in it along with Bridging file and accessed that file from objective-c file. It is also working fine.

Now I am trying to add second swift file. After adding it, I tried to access it in obj-c file but couldn't.

I checked with "ProductName-Swift.h" file. It has interface declaration for first file alone. Second file declaration is missing.

Any help please?

Comment: How did you build your second Swift file? Is it a struct, enum, class? If it uses Swift only features, then it will not be visible to Objective-C code. If it is built as a normal subclass of `NSObject` and everything looks like normal Objective-C code written in Swift, try a clean/build and check the "-Swift.h" file again to see if it updated. Check out the [Using Swift from Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) docs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a bridging header file if you want to import a Swift file to Objective-C.. Let's say your .swift is is `SomeFile.swift`. Then you import it using

```
#import "SomeFile-Swift.h"
```

See more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html